# Describing loci geometrically

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've been asked to geometrically describe the following loci:

Im(z)=3i

the solution is a horizontal line but I dont see why. please help.

my thoughts is that z=x+3i says all the y-intecepts are at 3i in the complex plane with x taking any value, but that kind of thinking feels flawed.

Comment: Hint. Draw a picture of the complex plane on which you mark some of the points that satisfy that equation.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker I get the y-position fixed at 3i while x can take any value on its number line. is that the correct way of thinking about it?

Comment: Technically, the imaginary part of a complex number is the real number that's multiplied by $i$, not the imaginary product formed by this multiplication. Thus properly, $\text{Im}(z)=3$.

Comment: Yes, You are overthinking this. There is nothing flawed about your understanding. But the points in the plane don't have "$y$-intercepts".

Comment: @OscarLanzi are you saying that Im(3i) is the same as Im(3)? I don't understand where and how my thinking is wrong

Comment: No, I am saying $\text{Im}(3i)$ is not $3i$ but just $3$. And $\text{Im}(3)$ where there is nothing multiplied by $i$ is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Im(z)=3i Means that the imaginary part of the complex number, z (= x + iy) is 3.

In the 2 dimensional representation of complex numbers, the complex plane or Argand diagram, the representation of all complex numbers whose imaginary part is 3i, would be a horizontal line at the level 3i.